# always get "502 Bad gateway" when use app engine VM

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to use the app engine VM for my project (env: Go). But am having problems I still haven't been able to resolve after days of searching:

1. I can't use the package "google.golang.org/appengine" and "google.golang.org/cloud/*"
   When I deploy my code which contains the above packages I can deploy successfully, but when I access the URL, return always "502 Bad Gateway".
   If I deploy the code without the above package, all works very well
2. The problem above happens after an update some of my package. Because I get this problem after I did "go get -u ...", before that all works well
3. When I see the last commit here (package "google.golang.org/appengine"): https://github.com/golang/appengine/commit/25b8450bec636c6b6e3b9b33d3a3f55230b10812
   I don't understand when replace "package helloworld" -> "package main". If I depoy with "package main", I don't know how to access the handler. For example:

`func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)
    appengine.Main()
}`

After deploy, how to test?? Because "my_app.appspot.com/hello" return 404, page not found

I don't know if there is someone else having the same problem. Please help, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you get 502 because of panic on attempt to get Context. You can see it with command `sudo docker logs -f gaeapp` after connecting to VM instance via ssh.

It seems that all examples for appengine vm are broken and you should use `init()`, not `main()` for initialization:

```
package notmainpackage

import (
  "net/http"

  "google.golang.org/appengine"
  "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
    appengine.Main()
}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
   log.Infof(ctx, "got appengine context")
}
```

Comment: What do you do with the 'main' function? Leave it empty? I cant deploy to app engine unless I have one.

Comment: If you are using a flexible env then you must have a main(){}